# What is this growing in my lawn?

Tags: identification, lawn

This moving from a rental to owning a home and having lawn care is certainly a learning experience... We're working to have a lawn of St. Augustine grass here in Southwest Florida. I've successfully helped out an area using plugs, but have much of the yard (probably around 40%) with areas where there grow up a few days after cutting. Are these weeds or a type of grass? I tried uploading an image to Google Image search but didn't get any help. Thanks!

[Lawn Weed or Seed http://www.unkfrank.com/images/StackExchange/GrassWeedSeed.jpg](http://www.unkfrank.com/images/StackExchange/GrassWeedSeed.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sedge or more commonly known around here as Sawgrass for the nasty cuts you can get off the leaves.

It's found in swamps and overly wet areas in your lawn.

Catch the seed heads before they mature.

[image]

Comment: Are the little "spikes" (What are they called? They remind me of a mace ;-) ) how this propagates?

Comment: Looks like its in the flowering stage (stigma). The spikes get replaced by what looks like green rolled oats which are the seeds. I use a spading fork to loosen the soil so the plant can be pulled out and throw the plant in the trash. If you're into composting, cut off the seed heads and send them to the dump. Then toss the rest on the heap.

Comment: So if I am mowing the lawn with these visible, I'm not spreading seeds, am I? Or do these stigma keep developing and turning into seeds as they lay on the ground?

Comment: Added an image so you can see what the seeds look like. Initially, they're green. I don't trust they won't mature out, so anything with a seed on it gets taken off the property, green or not.

Comment: Thanks for the additional image, Fiasco Labs. I haven't seen the matured seeds in the lawn. But looks like I have my work cut out for me... if it ever dries out enough to not need waders and an air boat in the front yard ;-)

Comment: Sedges are tough to get rid of.  The root system underground is quite extensive and comes back over and over.  A chemical is probably going to have to be used imo.